# "Unknow type constant pool at position X" in tomcat logs since java 8

Tags: java, jsf, tomcat, jsf-2, tomcat8

I have a Java JSF2 web based application deployed on a Tomcat server, and since we moved to Java 8 / Tomcat 8 this error appears a lot in the tomcat output:

```
déc. 05, 2016 10:51:07 AM com.sun.faces.config.JavaClassScanningAnnotationScanner$ConstantPoolInfo containsAnnotation
GRAVE: Unknow type constant pool 0 at position 178
```

I tried different stuff to fix this warning but it always comes back.

Is this log a symptom of any issue ? Is it just a normal output? Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: In English, error message is _SEVERE_ (instead of GRAVE).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I was presenting the same problem

Today I updated my pom.xml file to jsf version: 2.2.15 and that ERROR log was gone.

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
   <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
   <version>${jsf.version}</version>
   <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
   <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
   <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
   <version>${jsf.version}</version>
   <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 8):

From my research it appears that this was a bug in JSF implementation and was fixed in JSF version 2.3.0-m02

Reported Bugs:
http://github.com/javaserverfaces/mojarra/issues/3736
https://github.com/javaserverfaces/mojarra/issues/3780

Where to obtain fixed versions of the JSF implementation
http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/javax/faces/javax.faces-api/2.2/
http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/glassfish/javax.faces/2.3.0-m02/

Or update maven POM dependency with (2.3.0-m02 or higher):

```
<groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
<artifactId>javax.faces</artifactId>
<version>2.3.0-m02</version>
```

Comment: Note: the links to the reported bugs are not working anymore. Relocated to https://github.com/javaserverfaces/mojarra/issues/3736 and https://github.com/javaserverfaces/mojarra/issues/3780

Comment: I've amended the answer to reflect the new URLs

Comment: Note: the links to the reported bugs are not working anymore (again). Relocated to https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/mojarra/issues/3736 and https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/mojarra/issues/3780

Answer (score 3):

I had the same same problem. I solved after updating my pom.xml file to 2.2.11.

```
<groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
<artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
<version>2.2.11</version>

<artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
<version>2.2.11</version>
```

The postConstruct wasn't been execute in some ManagedBean, without any error.