# JBoss EAP 7.2/Tomcat8, JSF PostConstruct/PreDestroy

Tags: java, tomcat, jsf, jboss7.x

I have migrated web application to the JBoss 7.2 and faced with issue related to the using PostConstruct/PreDestroy annotations. I tried this example for solving: 
http://ovaraksin.blogspot.com/2011/05/what-to-do-if-postconstruct-not-called.html
But without succuess. Could you please advise.

Thanks!

```
2019-08-25 15:47:49,420 INFO  [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.config] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 315) Initializing Mojarra 2.1.19 ( 20130213-1512 https://svn.java.net/svn/mojarra~svn/tags/2.1.19@11614) for context '/webapptest'
2019-08-25 15:47:51,065 INFO  [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.application] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 315) JSF1048: PostConstruct/PreDestroy annotations present.  ManagedBeans methods marked with these annotations will have said annotations processed.
2019-08-25 15:47:51,100 SEVERE [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.config] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 315) Unknow type constant pool 18 at position 27
2019-08-25 15:47:51,100 SEVERE [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.config] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 315) Unknow type constant pool 0 at position 28
2019-08-25 15:47:51,101 SEVERE [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.config] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 315) Unknow type constant pool 0 at position 29
2019-08-25 15:47:51,101 SEVERE [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.config] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 315) Unknow type constant pool 0 at position 30
2019-08-25 15:47:51,101 SEVERE [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.config] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 315) Unknow type constant pool -75 at position 31
2019-08-25 15:47:51,101 SEVERE [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.config] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 315) Unknow type constant pool 15 at position 181
2019-08-25 15:47:51,101 SEVERE [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.config] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 315) Unknow type constant pool 67 at position 186
2019-08-25 15:47:51,102 SEVERE [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.config] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 315) Unknow type constant pool 108 at position 187
2019-08-25 15:47:51,102 SEVERE [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.config] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 315) Unknow type constant pool 97 at position 188
2019-08-25 15:47:51,102 SEVERE [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.config] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 315) Unknow type constant pool 115 at position 189
2019-08-25 15:47:51,102 SEVERE [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.config] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 315) Unknow type constant pool 115 at position 190
2019-08-25 15:47:51,102 SEVERE [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.config] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 315) Unknow type constant pool 0 at position 254
2019-08-25 15:47:51,102 SEVERE [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.config] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 315) Unknow type constant pool 49 at position 255
2019-08-25 15:47:51,102 SEVERE [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.config] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 315) Unknow type constant pool 0 at position 256
2019-08-25 15:47:51,102 SEVERE [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.config] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 315) Unknow type constant pool 15 at position 257
2019-08-25 15:47:51,102 SEVERE [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.config] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 315) Unknow type constant pool 0 at position 258
2019-08-25 15:47:51,102 SEVERE [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.config] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 315) Unknow type constant pool 58 at position 259
2019-08-25 15:47:51,102 SEVERE [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.config] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 315) Unknow type constant pool 0 at position 260
```

Comment: I have switched on JSF longing of webcontainer.jsf = on and see the same issue under Tomcat

Comment: You also upgraded to java 8? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31194474/unable-to-start-jboss-as-7-1-1-final-with-jdk-8-on-windows-8-1-command-prompt

Comment: I did not migrate, I have already had JDK8. In which way it can related to the my issue?

Comment: You migrated to sth. not compatible to java 8 / Lambda expressions. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40971621/unknow-type-constant-pool-at-position-x-in-tomcat-logs-since-java-8

Comment: @Selaron, thank you. The jsf version has been updated to the 2.2.15 and logs looks fine.